# How to change Spark BorderContainer default height?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4

How to create horizontal layout container like HGroup but with border and border radius?

In this example there is some default height:

```
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" borderWeight="2" cornerRadius="5">
  <s:layout>
     <s:HorizontalLayout/>
  </s:layout>
  <s:Image source="image.png" />
  <mx:Text text="text example" />
</s:BorderContainer>
```

I want it to have height of the heighest element in container. Like in HGroup.

Add: Why is height for above example BorderContainer equal to 112 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nemi
Just set the **minHeight** property of the BorderContainer to **0**.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get height of the heighest element in container.

better my suggestion is to use like this

```
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="{hGroup.height}" borderWeight="2" cornerRadius="5">
  <s:HGroup width="100%" id="hGroup">
     <s:Image source="image.png" />
     <mx:Text text="text example" />    
  </s:HGroup>     
</s:BorderContainer>
```

This might set the highest child height to the borderContainer.

Comment: Thanks :) This gives what I want. So there is no way to have HGroup border? Maybe with CSS?